# Run external R script n times and save outputs in a data frame

Tags: r, knitr

I have a R script of several hundreds of lines including several randomization functions. Each time I run it I obtain a different result.

I am thinking of performing a sensitivity analysis of my model and I wold be interested in running my script hundreds of times and compare the results.

After some research, I found out that a combination of `lapply` and`knitr` could be a possible solution:

```
result <- c("B:/Documents/result.R")
resultsList <- lapply(1:100, function(n) knit(input=result, NULL))
```

Unfortunately this is not working. Could anyone explain me why?

Many thanks!

#### UPDATE

The script looks like this one:

```
#Records
dataID = c(01, 03, 05) 
localityNumber = c(2000, 4000, 5000) 
records = data.frame(dataID, localityNumber)

#Locality number / Postcode conversion table
localityNumber = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 4000, 5000)
postCode = c(6766, 6767, 6768, 7041, 8046) 
allocationTable = data.frame(localityNumber,postCode)

rm(dataID, localityNumber, postCode)

#Create random postcode id
count <- aggregate(allocationTable, by=list(allocationTable$localityNumber), FUN=length)
names(count) <- c("localityNumber", "count", "count.2")
allocationTable <- join(x=allocationTable, y=count)

#Test with for localityNumber with three postcodes
allocationThree <- allocationTable[which (allocationTable$count == "3"),]
testThree <- nrow(allocationThree) / 3
repThree <- rep(1:3, testThree)
allocationThree$id <- repThree
allocationThree$count <- allocationThree$count.2 <- NULL
rm(count, rep, testThree)

records$id <- repThree

#Randomly allocate
records <- join(records, allocationThree)
```

I would like to repeat this script several times and store the values of the `records` data.frame in a list.

Comment: `lapply(1:100, function(n)source("B:/Documents/result.R"))` no good?

Comment: Hi Khashaa, thank you for your input. I tried the `source` method: `lapply(1:100, function(n) source(result))` but I get a list with a list of 2 arguments (`value` and `visible`) for the 100 repetitions. I think it is the right direction, but I would like to get a list including the output results of the script, not simply run it.

Comment: what does your script look like?

Comment: @Gion Mors it would be nice if you could provide a pseudo code of your function or name , or a brief info about your function etc

Comment: Urgh... tough question! The script allocates postcodes randomly for a set of records. The output is a data frame with the record ID and the allocated postcode. Since the script randomizes the allocation, each time I run it, the values of the postcode variable change. I hope I answered your question!

Comment: Can you provide a short dummy script resembling your original script?

Comment: Here, I modified the question to include a sample of the script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `records` add the end of your script so that it outputs the `records` dataframe.

You can then run:

```
result_list<-lapply(1:100, function(n)source("your_script.R"))
```

If you want to `rbind` all the dataframes, you can do:

```
do.call(cbind,lapply(result_list,function(x) x$value))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to wrap the script into a function by putting:

```
my_function <- function() {
```

at the top and

```
}
```

at the bottom.

That way, you could `source` it once then then use `ldply` from the plyr package:

```
results <- rdply(100, myFunction())
```

If you wanted a column to identify which iteration, you could use:

```
results <- ldply(1:100, function(i) data.frame(iteration = i, myFunction())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following command; Note that you can change the times to whatever number you want

```
repeatedfunction <- c(mapply(list, FUN=**the name of your function** (args),times=100 ))
```

Comment: Hi Nemo! Thank you! I will definetly use `lapply` or `mapply` for the loop part of my problem. The issue is how to to include the script output in the function. This is not working: `repeatedfunction <- c(mapply(list, FUN=source(result),times=100 ))`.

Comment: @Gion Mors what do you get as error? if there is no error, how the repeated function looks like ?

Comment: @Gion Mors this one helps replicate(100, the_name_of_your_function(agrs), simplify="matrix")      args is the data input for your function . In your function , do you have any return ? if so, can you tell me what you return ?

Comment: That's the error: `Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'source(inputTest)' is not a function, a charter chain or a symbol`