# Run external R script n times, with different input paramters, and save outputs in a data frame

Tags: r, loops

my question ties to the following problem:

[Run external R script n times and save outputs in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792801/run-external-r-script-n-times-and-save-outputs-in-a-data-frame)

The difference is, that I dont generate different results by randomization functions but would like to use every time a different set of input variables (e.g. run the chunk of code for a range of latitudes  lat=c(50,60,70,80))

Has anyone a hint for me? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wrap your script in a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the script into a function by putting:

```
my_function <- function(latitude) {
```

at the top and

```
}
```

at the bottom.

That way, you could `source` it once then then use `ldply` from the plyr package:

```
results <- ldply(10 * 5:8, myFunction)
```

If you wanted a column to identify which latitude was used, you could either add that to your function's data.frame or use:

```
results <- ldply(10 * 5:8, function(lat) data.frame(latitude = lat, myFunction())
```

If for some reason you didn't want to modify your script, you could create a wrapper function:

```
my_wrapper <- function(a) {
  latitude <- a
  source("script.R", local = TRUE)$value
}
```

or even use `eval` and `parse`:

```
my_function <- eval(parse(text = c("function(latitude) {",
  readLines("script.R"), "}")))
```